# How to convert list of objects from one type to an other

Tags: .net, converters, object-type

I have two objects.

```
class User{
 public int id{get;set;}
 public string name{get;set;}
}

class UserProtectedDetails{
 public string name{get;set;}
}
```

How can I convert `List<User>` to `List<UserProtectedDetails>`?

I know how to do it in reflection, but is there anyway to do it in Linq or other .NET way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there anyway to do it in linq or other .net way?

Sure:

```
List<User> list = ...; // Make your user list
List< UserProtectedDetails> = list
    .Select(u => new UserProtectedDetails{name=u.name})
    .ToList();
```

**EDIT:** (in response to a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018504/how-to-convert-list-of-objects-from-one-type-to-an-other/12018521#comment16036440_12018521)) If you would like to avoid the `{name = u.name}` part, you need either (1) a function that makes a mapping for you, or (2) a constructor of `UserProtectedDetails` that takes a `User` parameter:

```
UserProtectedDetails(User u) {
    name = u.name;
}
```

One way or the other, the `name = u.name` assignment needs to be made somewhere.

Comment: can that be without mentioning name=u.name? just take all matchers thanks

Comment: You can also take a look at [implicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx) and [explicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4.aspx) casting (though I agree a constructor accepting this parameter may be best as long as they're both in the same assembly and it doesn't create a dependancy).

Answer (score 0):

Well, it could be as easy as

```
var userList = new List<User>();

var userProtectedDetailsList = userList.Select(u => 
    new UserProtectedDetails { name = u.name }
)
.ToList();
```

Comment: can that be without mentioning name=u.name? just take all matchers thanks

Comment: @SexyMF In that case, I think you would need to use reflection or some kind of auto mapper. Add that to your question if that's really what you are looking for =)